# renaming file name by id

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, codeigniter-2

i am trying to rename an image file and save the file location in database. i am having problem problem with it, as i want to name the file as the id of the table row i am inserting in.
after uploading and inserting i want to see my table as like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| id | name | category | image         |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | foo  | category | uploads/1.jpg |
----------------------------------------
```

the id field is auto incremented.
here is my code for it:

```
function service()
{
    $con=$this->do_upload();
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
    $data=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
        'image'=>'uploads/'.$id.$con['file_ext'];
     );
    $query=$this->db->insert('table',$data);
    return $query;
}
```

this is not the correct way and as assumed the file is not saved in the database as wanted.instead of saving it as 'uploads/1.jpg' it is saved as 'uploads/0.jpg'.
 can any one provide me the right convention to do it?
n.b. i am using **codeigniter 2.1.0** and **mySQL** database.

Comment: We assume you know you're missing a `$` on `con` --> `$id.con['file_ext'];`

Comment: What happens inside the function `do_upload()`? If the connection gets closed or some other database action happens, you may lose `INSERT_ID`

Comment: Filename should not contain "upload/", probably you are saving all your files in that directory,so name the file as "image1.jpg"

Comment: You are infusing meaning onto your primary key.  You may may instead wish to add a column with a file name to avoid synchronization issues if your keys need to packed or something changes later.

Comment: in do_upload(), the image is uploaded in the uploads directory in the server by codeigniters file_uploading class, no database call is done in there.as i have come to know that i cannot access id with my_sql_insert_id without calling mysql query before. then how do i name the file as id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access id with `mysql_insert_id` without calling mysql query before. You have to insert new record and then update it. with new filename.

Edit:

When I was uploading images/other files to the server, I was always renaming them with some random hash. So files had unique hash name on filesystem and in mysql row there was set just this hash to associate db row with file.

So before inserting new record into db, generate some random string with checking if file with this name already exists:

```
$filename = '';
do {
  $filename = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8);
} while ( !file_exists('uploads/'.$filename) );
```

Do it in `do_upload` method and let it to return file's name in `$con` array.

Comment: what hsz said is correct. You will need to add the file to the file system, add the record to the db. return the last ID #, and then rename the file, and then finally requery the db to update the row with the new filename..

 **suggestion** name the file as timestamp, and store that timestamp in the db. One less query to the db. and just as unique.

Comment: in regards to load (although minimal) a random hash takes more resources than a time() call. Out of the two a time() call would be the better route.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use a unique value for your `id` field you could do like this:

```
function update_service($id)
{
   $con=$this->do_upload();
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM <table_name>");
   $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   $id = $data[0] + 1; 
   $data=array(
       'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
       'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
       'image'=>'uploads/'.$id.$con['file_ext'];
   );
   $query=$this->db->insert('table',$data);
   return $query;
}
```

Comment: This solution can causes data inaccuracy. Quick scenario: we have 10 records, so last id is `10`, so `$id=11`. but if we delete last 5 records, it will be `$id=6`. MySQL's autoincrement will insert new recod with `id=11` and we're going to use `$id=6`. Do not do it this way !

Comment: thank u @krister but is there any other way of doing it without making two database calls?

Comment: @hsz, then how do you suggest to do it? i am pretty novice in these cases.

Comment: @Shabib - Like already said, you would have to first make a insert query, and then use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the `id` of you newly inserted row. Then you would have to update that row based on this `id`. You could also use @Mikes approach and use a timestamp or similar to get rid of the extra query.

Answer (score 1):

```
function service()
{
    $con=$this->do_upload();
    $id = time();
    $data=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
        'image'=>'uploads/'.$id.$con['file_ext'];
     );
    $query=$this->db->insert('table',$data);
    return $query;
}
```

using `time()` instead of mysql_insert_id.. then you just need to do the same thing in the `do_upload()` function.. where it asks for filename just use `time()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have built in the same functionality in one of my apps. I am using a uuid generator class which I downloaded from here: https://github.com/Repox/codeigniter-uuid.

Using this class I am generating uuid's for newly uploaded images and then set the filename to ".ext". I am storing the uuid in a database field as well for the user who has uploaded the image to have a reference to the file name.

It's working pretty well for me.

So a code snippet looks like this:

```
$this->load->library('uuid');
$uuid = $this->uuid->v4();
$new_file_name = $uuid.$image_data['file_ext'];
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards
Sebastian

Comment: That's one of many ways to implement a sequence like behavior.
In regards to teh original question, it seems that using $id=mysql_insert_id(); should be done AFTER the insert, not before:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm